# Is it possible to perform an action based on the id of a radio button in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display an output depending on which radio button is selected. Is there a way to expand on this:

> ($('input[name="opco"]:checked').length > 0)

to include the radio button id? Something like this:

> ($('input[name="opco"][id="MPC"]:checked').length > 0)

The HTML for this example is as follows:

```
<section id="first" class="section">
     <div class="container">
        <form name="operatingCompany">
           <h3>1.What OPERATING COMPANY Are You Employeed With?</h3>
           <input type="radio" name="opco" id="GPC" value="GPC" >GPC</br>
           <input type="radio" name="opco" id="APC" value="APC" >APC</br>
           <input type="radio" name="opco" id="MPC" value="MPC" >MPC</br>
           <input type="radio" name="opco" id="Gulf"value="Gulf" >Gulf</br>
           <input type="radio" name="opco" id="SCS" value="SCS" >SCS</br></br>
           <!-- <input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_opco() /> -->
        </form>
        <p id="opco_result"> </p>
        </br>
     </div>  <!---------------------------------------------------------Prototyped Question----------------------------------->
     <div class="container">
        <form name="prototyped">
           <h3>2.Has the innovation been PROTOTYPED?</h3>
           <input type="radio" name="prototyped" id="Yes1" value="Yes" >Yes</br>
           <input type="radio" name="prototyped" id="No1"  value="No" >No</br></br>
           <!-- <input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_prototype() /> -->
        </form>
        <p id="prototyped_result"> </p>
        </br>
     </div>
     <!--------------------------------------------------------Adopted or Tested Question---------------------------->
     <div class="container">
        <form name="adopted_tested">
           <h3>3.Has the innovation been ADOPTED OR TESTED?</h3>
           <input type="radio" name="adopt" id="Yes2" value="Yes" >Yes</br>
           <input type="radio" name="adopt" id="No2"  value="No" >No</br></br>
           <!-- <input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_adopt_test() /> -->
        </form>
        <p id="adopted_tested_result"> </p>
        </br>
     </div>
     <!------------------------------------------------------Can it make money Question------------------------------->
     <div class="container">
        <form name="makeMoney">
           <h3>4.Is this a PRODUCT OR SERVICE that can make MONEY?</h3>
           <input type="radio" name="money" id="Yes3" value="Yes" >Yes</br>
           <input type="radio" name="money" id="No3"  value="No" >No</br></br>
           <!-- <input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_money() /> -->
        </form>
        <p id="makeMoney_result"> </p>
        </br>
     </div>
     <!------------------------------------------------IT Specific Question------------------------------------------->
     <div class="container">
        <form name="innovativeTechnology">
           <h3>5.Is your innovation an INNOVATIVE TECHNOLOGY or process that boosts the company's PRODUCTIVITY or brings additional value from a VENDOR RELATIONSHIP?</h3>
           <input type="radio" name="innovative" id="Yes4" value="Yes" >Yes</br>
           <input type="radio" name="innovative" id="No4"  value="No" >No</br></br>
           <!-- <input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_innovative() /> -->
        </form>
        <p id="innovativeTechnology_result"> </p>
        </br>
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Submit Form" onclick="get_recommendation(); get_lastOpco(); openNav()">
     </div>
     <!--------------------------------------------Side Menu PopUp--------------------------------------------------------->
     <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <br></br>
        <h1> Based on your selections, we recommend the following: </h1>
        <div id="myPrimarydiv" class="primarydiv">
           <a h2><span id="primary"></span></h2>
        </div>
        <br></br>
        <div id="mySecondarydiv" class="secondarydiv">
           <a h2><span id="secondary"></span></h2>
        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
```

JQuery:

```
if (($('#MPC').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes1').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes2').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes3').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes4').is(':checked'))){
        var primary = ("Primary Recommendation: " + OS);
        var secondary = ("Secondary Recommendation: " + ES);
    }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select an element in jquery with two attribiutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237383/select-an-element-in-jquery-with-two-attribiutes)

Answer (score 2):

Since ID's must be unique and they have selectors already you can simply do something like this

```
if ($('#MPC').is(':checked')){
    var primary = ("Primary Recommendation: " + OS);
    var secondary = ("Secondary Recommendation: " + ES);
}
```

To do specific actions when the value changes, you can check the id of the current active radio button in the change event

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="opco"]').change(function(){
    switch(this.id){
        case 'MPC':
            //Do something etc
            break;

    }
});
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, instead of being downvoted

Comment: Have to love when people downvote with no comment as to why ;)

Comment: @bhmahler we face often at SO. It's no issue. Ignore them.

Comment: @bhmahler thank you for your response. I have updated my post with your recommendation. For some reason I am not having successful results (I know I am the problem here). What am I missing? The output is blank. I also tried exactly what you recommended as well and it yielded a blank output. Thanks!